# Installing geopandas through conda forces me to remove basemap (windows 8)

Tags: python, pip, geopandas, fiona

I am trying to install geopandas into a virtual environment for implementing new code to a script that already relies on the hardest thing on planet earth to install, basemap. Unfortunately, conda seems adamant on removing the forsaken package when I try to install geopandas. It also demands a bunch of updates, which are historically very bad for old scripts, and often break them completely.

The issue is Fiona, and I can do the whole pip install of the wheel file, but is there anyway for this to not be a horrific mess like it usually is?

Here's what conda says when I try to install geopands:

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    click:           7.0-py_0
    click-plugins:   1.1.1-py_0
    cligj:           0.5.0-py37_0
    curl:            7.67.0-h2a8f88b_0
    expat:           2.2.5-he025d50_0
    fiona:           1.8.4-py37h22081e2_0
    freexl:          1.0.5-hfa6e2cd_0
    gdal:            2.3.3-py37hdf43c64_0
    geopandas:       0.6.1-py_0
    hdf4:            4.2.13-h712560f_2
    kealib:          1.4.7-h07cbb95_6
    krb5:            1.16.4-hc04afaa_0
    libboost:        1.67.0-hd9e427e_4
    libcurl:         7.67.0-h2a8f88b_0
    libgdal:         2.3.3-h10f50ba_0
    libkml:          1.3.0-he5f2a48_4
    libnetcdf:       4.6.1-h411e497_2
    libpq:           11.2-h3235a2c_0
    libspatialindex: 1.9.3-h33f27b4_0
    libspatialite:   4.3.0a-hc36aec2_19
    libssh2:         1.8.2-h7a1dbc1_0
    munch:           2.5.0-py_0
    pcre:            8.43-ha925a31_0
    rtree:           0.8.3-py37_0
    shapely:         1.6.4-py37h222a598_0
    xerces-c:        3.2.2-ha925a31_0

The following packages will be REMOVED:

    basemap:         1.2.0-py37h4e5d7af_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    ca-certificates: 2019.1.23-0            --> 2019.11.27-0
    certifi:         2019.3.9-py37_0        --> 2019.11.28-py37_0
    geos:            3.6.2-h9ef7328_2       --> 3.7.1-h33f27b4_0
    openssl:         1.1.1b-he774522_1      --> 1.1.1d-he774522_3
    vs2015_runtime:  14.15.26706-h3a45250_0 --> 14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_1

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Comment: Use conda to create a new environment for `geopandas` and install `geopandas` in that new environment. On the new environment, install `cartopy` if you need mapping package.

Comment: You can try to pin the versions to older releases to avoid updating of some of them, but you need to be sure they are compatible.

Comment: I created a copy of the virtual environment, then installed fiona just to see what happened. It uninstalled basemap as it said it would, but then I reinstalled basemap, which uninstalled fiona, but then when I reinstalled fiona a second time, they were able to coexist. Strange behaviour, but I guess that solved it. After that, I was also able to install geopandas without any issues.